# Sympy, find sum of an infinite series/summation that contains a complex number

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

How do I find the sum of an infinite series that contains a complex number.

Here are two examples of such infinite series:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can express these as Sums

```
>>> from sympy import I, oo, Sum, exp, pi
>>> from sympy.abc import n
>>> Sum((I/3)**n,(n,0,oo)).doit()
9/10 + 3*I/10
>>> Sum(exp(I*pi*n/2)/2**n,(n,0,oo)).doit()
Sum(2**(-n)*exp(I*pi*n/2), (n, 0, oo))
```

Even though the 2nd one doesn't evaluate, it can be evaluated

```
>>> _.n()
0.8 + 0.4*I
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you evaluated the 2nd one? What does "_" and ".n()" refer to? You haven't defined "_" anyhwere.

Comment: Running the 2nd one result in an error: https://gyazo.com/65b47b9738f1f684c5262a50382ef43e

Comment: Check to see that you have the latest SymPy. The `_.n()` means "evaluate the last output numerically." "n" is a method that evaluates an expression numerically (if possible), e.g. `pi.n(2)` -> 3.14.

Comment: I am running sympy '1.4' (aka. the newest version). What version are you running? https://gyazo.com/4f03307d582df10129f70bc672e25295

Comment: interactive display with `sympy.__version__ -> 1.5.dev`

Comment: Wierd, I can't install sympy version (1.5.dev), it isn't each an option with pip install (https://gyazo.com/573c8a6b5ac1c9aae604a8b710bf1314) I guess you installed that version manually somehow.

Comment: I initially set this up following the directions at https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Development-workflow